# Determine if a microsoft account is logged in on the current browser usingn javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have a website that has a SSO log in method. If the user click the sign in, it will automatically log in the user using the microsoft account the is logged in on the browser.

But I added a functionality to have an internal log in, so currently there are two ways of sign in, first, is the SSO, second is using the credentials created by the website.

What I want to achieve is to detect if there is a microsoft account that is currently logged in in the browser so the SSO login method will automatically triggered.

E.g

```
If("There is a microsoft logged in on the current browser"){
sso function will trigger
}else{
window.location.href="www.domain.com/signin"
}
```

Comment: What code have you written in an attempt to satisfy the requirement you detailed above, and where *specifically* are you getting stuck in that attempt? Questions here are expected to include some indication of how you’ve attempted to help yourself before posting here, in accordance with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi so, to be honest Im using a low code framework, powerapps portals if your are familiar. The initial requirement is to have two pages with external and internal(SSO) login, But base on my research and analysis, the power apps portal doesn't allow user to create new sign in page, so I tried a different work around and did a trial and error, and found out how can I put a custom script on the sign in page.

Comment: depending how sso was implemented, there maybe a cookie that you can use to see if user already has an active session